# NSMutableURLRequest custom header causing request to fail

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, http, http-headers, nsurlrequest

I am making a `GET` request for `JSON` data from a server that requires custom headers. The server responds with accurate response codes when I add the authentication header but fails during the custom header.

This -

```
[request addValue:utcDate forHTTPHeaderField:@"­X-Custom-Date"];
```

causes the request to not receive a response from the server.

I can add the identical headers in a curl command and get a response so it is something particular to the `NSMutableURLRequest` class.

Has anyone encounter this issue?

Comment: What is `utcDate`? A string? Have you checked what is actually sent? Server log?

Comment: I recommend using `tcpdump` on the command line to confirm that what you're sending is what you expect, and to see if you get any response from the server or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP header in the above question was copied from an PDF API document. Apparently it pasted in a character that is not displayed and caused the request to fail.

You can copy the above request line into a program like vi and you will find the additional character before the X.

I have been searching for a way to force Xcode to display ALL characters without success.